# Obter texto dentro de input com input-group-addon de radiobutton

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Tenho esse form com esses inputs, quero obter o valor que esta dentro do input do radio button selecionado, exemplo como na imagem, eu deveria obter "bb".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu html:

```
<label>Respostas:</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <input type="radio" name="respostacorreta">
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pergunta1">
                        </div><!-- /input-group -->
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <input type="radio" name="respostacorreta">
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pergunta2" >
                        </div><!-- /input-group -->
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <input type="radio" name="respostacorreta" >
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pergunta3">
                        </div><!-- /input-group -->
```

Meu jquery até então, estou obtendo apenas o texto de todos os campos:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#btnenviarnoticia').click(function() {
            var btn = $(this);
            btn.button('loading');
            var respostas = [$('#pergunta1').val(),$('#pergunta2').val(),$('#pergunta3').val()];
            alert(respostas);

        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para pegar o `input` selecionado use:

```
$('input[name="respostacorreta"]:checked')
```

E depois suba um Nivel usando `.parent()` para pegar o próximo input que existe

**Exemplo**:

*Fiquei com preguiça de carregar o Bootstrap*

```js
$('button').click(function(){
    var resposta = $('input[name="respostacorreta"]:checked').parent().next('input').val();
    alert(resposta);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Respostas:</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <input type="radio" name="respostacorreta">
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pergunta1">
                        </div><!-- /input-group -->
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <input type="radio" name="respostacorreta">
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pergunta2" >
                        </div><!-- /input-group -->
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon">
                                <input type="radio" name="respostacorreta" >
                            </span>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pergunta3">
                        </div><!-- /input-group -->
                        
             
 <br>
<button>Ação!</button>
```

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Baseado [nesta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596351/how-can-i-know-which-radio-button-is-selected-via-jquery):

```
$('input[name=radioName]:checked', '#myForm').val()
```